# RxJava2 Error Handling Wrapper For Retrofit Service

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I need to handle error globally in my application for network service, i am using Rxjava2CallAdapterFactory in my retrofit service. So In order to handle error globally i searched through various sites and i got a solution. But i do know how this works.

```
class RxErrorAdapter private constructor() : CallAdapter.Factory() {

    private val original = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()

    override fun get(returnType: Type, annotations: Array<Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): CallAdapter<*, *>? {
        return Wrapper<Any>(original.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit)
                ?: return null)
    }

    private class Wrapper<R>(private val wrapped: CallAdapter<R, *>) : CallAdapter<R, Any> {

        override fun responseType(): Type {
            return wrapped.responseType()
        }

        override fun adapt(call: Call<R>): Any {
            val result = wrapped.adapt(call)
        }
    }


    companion object {
        fun create(): CallAdapter.Factory {
            return RxErrorAdapter()
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `RxJava2CallAdapter` already knows how to **adapt** a return type `Call<T>` to `Observable<T>`, `Completable` and other Rx types,
`RxErrorCallAdapterFactory` asks the original factory `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` to create such "original" `RxJava2CallAdapter`. Then `RxErrorCallAdapterFactory` creates its own `CallAdapter` - `RxCallAdapterWrapper`, with that original adapter inside.

So `RxErrorCallAdapterFactory` gives out `RxCallAdapterWrapper` which first delegates to the original `RxJava2CallAdapter` to convert `Call<User>` to `Observable<User>`, and then applies `onErrorResumeNext()` operator ontop of `Observable<User>`.

When an error occurs during network request (e.g. 400 Bad Request from the server) it will be propagated to that `onErrorResumeNext()` where you can apply your error-mapping logic. In this case `onErrorResumeNext()` takes `Throwable` and returns `Observable` that signals `onError()` with mapped `Throwable`.

Basically, if original `CallApater` returns `Observable.just(User())`, wrapper `CallAdapter` will return this:

```
    Observable.just(User())
        .onErrorResumeNext { throwable -> 
            Observable.error(map(throwable))
        }
```